# Image pop when hover over a list in HTML/JS/JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want those images to be visible when i hover them over the text. But according to this it works but it selects the first one only as there is same id for every images. Please any one know to fix this problem. This is my first post. Pls excuse if i had done anything wrong in posting. Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery_ui.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

        <style>
            #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
            #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
            #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
            #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 20%; }
            #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }

            img
            {
                position:absolute;
                left:250px;
                display:none;
            }
        </style>

        <script>        
            $(function() {
                $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table id="myTable">
            <td>
                <tr>
                    <ol id="selectable" onmouseover="show(next,true)" onmouseout="show(next,false)">
                        <li>Item 1 <img src="next.jpg" id="next"></li>
                        <li>Item 2 <img src="next.jpg" id="next"></li>
                        <li>Item 3 <img src="next.jpg" id="next"></li>
                        <li>Item 4 <img src="next.jpg" id="next"></li>
                        <li>Item 5 <img src="next.jpg" id="next"></li>
                    </ol>
                </tr>
            </td>
        </table>

        <script type = "text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#selectable').fadeIn('very slow');
            });
        </script>

        <script language="javascript">
        //function to display the immage
            function show(id,disp) {
                if (disp == true) {
                    id.style.display = "block";
                }

                if (disp == false) {
                    id.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cant have id's named the same. Use classes. `The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one.` [Read about it here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following As u are using ID for processing , Make id different

```
<li>Item 1 <img src="next.jpg" id="next1" ></li>
<li>Item 2 <img src="next.jpg" id="next2" ></li>
<li>Item 3 <img src="next.jpg" id="next3" ></li>
<li>Item 4 <img src="next.jpg" id="next4" ></li>
<li>Item 5 <img src="next.jpg" id="next5" ></li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. but i already thought of it and i didnt know how to pass it.

Comment: @Vithushan , wat u did not know how to pass id ?

Comment: @Vithushan , Can't u generate <img> tag with Dynamic id ? U have to implement this approach only as if u use class IT WILL BE APPLICABBLE to all ELEMENTS , img tags

Answer (score 0):

The id of the elements should not be the same. You can have a same class instead and pass the class name in the show function.

Update: have the mouseover and mouseout event on individual lis rather than ol to get that particular element.

```
<ol id="selectable">
  <li>Item 1 <img src="next.jpg" class="next"  onmouseover="show(this,true)" onmouseout="show(next,false)"></li>
    <li>Item 2 <img src="next.jpg" class="next"  onmouseover="show(this,true)" onmouseout="show(next,false)"></li>
    <li>Item 3 <img src="next.jpg" class="next"  onmouseover="show(this,true)" onmouseout="show(next,false)"></li>
    <li>Item 4 <img src="next.jpg" class="next"  onmouseover="show(this,true)" onmouseout="show(next,false)"></li>
    <li>Item 5 <img src="next.jpg" class="next"  onmouseover="show(this,true)" onmouseout="show(next,false)"></li>
</ol>
```

Your show function:

```
function show(clickedObj,disp) {
    if (disp == true) {
        clickedObj.style.display = "block";
    }

    if (disp == false) {
        clickedObj.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. But it didnt work. I assume that even thought we pass by class as the name is same it takes the first element. Do you have any idea sir??

Comment: i assume this works when we hover the mouse over the image only as its declared in image instance. Again thank you for replying

Comment: It will select the applicable li this time. If it answered your query do mark it as your answer